# Storing workflow state with Jolie

Tags: jolie

I am trying to understand how Jolie achieves resiliency for workflows.

- Does Jolie store the state of running workflows?
- Does it do so by using databases or file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix three components of the Jolie language to save/load the state of a workflow and program fault-recovery code:

- Jolie variables, which are trees;
- some standard libraries to support marshalling and unmarshalling of Jolie trees and file/database interactions;
- the language [fault handling mechanisms](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/fault-handling/basics) for handling exceptional behaviours.

The state of an instance of a Jolie microservice is a tree (similar to XML and JSON structures). In practice, while in Jolie `a = 5` recalls the familiar variable assignment found in other languages, what actually happens is that, in the state of the instance executing the assignment, we create a node `a` and assign to `a` the value `5`. Vice versa, when we write `a` in a Jolie program we are accessing the value stored under the node `a`. Similarly, `a.b = 6` means creating a subnode `b` under `a` and assigning to it the value `6`.

Having native tree data-structures in the language is very useful when sending and receiving structured data, since Jolie automatically converts its tree-shaped variables into the format used to communicate with some external client/server, via its Ports. However, tree-shaped variables are also fairly easy to marshal/unmarshal. E.g., we can convert the current status of a Jolie tree-variable by calling the [JSON](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/standard-library-api/jsonutils) (or XML) library and either use the [File](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/standard-library-api/file) or [Database](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/standard-library-api/database) libraries for persistence.

I assembled below a simple example to illustrate my point. In the example, I use the procedures `saveState` and `loadState` to save and load the values stored under variable `process_state`, which is the root variable containing all relevant values used in the workflow. The workflow starts from the `main` block, where we save some data and print it for reference (operations `valueToPrettyString` and `println`). Then, we save the current state (`saveState`) and continue with `stage1`. Since variable `process_state.c` equals `"bad"` we throw a fault (`MyFault`). The `install` block catches the fault and executes the procedure `recv_stage1`. The procedure discards the previous, faulty status of the program, restores the one saved on file and "repairs" variable `process_state.c`. Done that, we execute `stage1` again.

```
include "console.iol"
include "json_utils.iol"
include "string_utils.iol"
include "file.iol"

define saveState
{
  getJsonString@JsonUtils( process_state )( marshalled_state.content );
  writeFile@File( marshalled_state )();
  undef( marshalled_state.content )
}

define loadState {
  undef( process_state );
  readFile@File( marshalled_state )( marshalled_state.content );
  getJsonValue@JsonUtils( marshalled_state.content )( process_state );
  undef( marshalled_state.content )
}

define recv_stage1 {
  scope( recv_stage1 ){
     loadState;
     process_state.c = "fine";
     valueToPrettyString@StringUtils( process_state )( state_pretty_print );
     println@Console( state_pretty_print )()
  }
}

define stage1 {
  scope( stage1 ){
    install( MyFault => 
      println@Console( "MyFault, loading saved state" )(); recv_stage1; stage1 );
    if ( process_state.c == "bad" ){
      throw( MyFault )
    } else {
      println@Console( "Everything went " + process_state.c )()
    }
  }
}

main
{
  marshalled_state.filename = "instance_XXX.json";
  with ( process_state ){
    .a = 42;
    .b << "I" { .love = "very", .much = "jolie" };
    valueToPrettyString@StringUtils( process_state )( state_pretty_print );
    println@Console( state_pretty_print )();
    saveState;
    .c = "bad";
    stage1
  }
}
```

This kind of staging can be used to also recover from crashes (e.g., by indicating into a variable which was the last stage reached).

Jolie also offers some advanced constructs to handle the [termination and compensation](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/fault-handling/termination_and_compensation) of workflows, useful to avoid saving corrupted stages and enforce transactional behaviours.

References

- Fabrizio Montesi, Claudio Guidi, & Gianluigi Zavattaro. (2014). Service-Oriented Programming with Jolie. In A. Bouguettaya, Q. Z. Sheng, & F. Daniel (Eds.), Web Services Foundations (pp. 81–107). Springer https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-7518-7_4
- Fabrizio Montesi, Claudio Guidi, Ivan Lanese, & Gianluigi Zavattaro. (2008). Dynamic Fault Handling Mechanisms for Service-Oriented Applications. https://doi.org/10.1109/ECOWS.2008.20